# Instant ping lost alert

Tags: networking, ping, nagios, cacti

I am used to run Nagios over the years, and it have been great. But recently our business unit have a requirement to alert whenever a packet loss appear, and Nagios plugin simple can't do the trick because it could ping every minute. Is there have any constant ping test and alert solution? It doesn't have to be with Nagios, some outside the box solution would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program called Metaping to constantly monitor the ping of any IP address or host name. it will tell you right away if the ping goes down by the way of a graph.

Comment: any open source program available?